# Error reading Custom Configuration Section: No parameterless constructor defined for this object

Tags: configuration, web-config, configurationsection, custom-configuration

Having a horrible time reading a custom configuration section from web.config:
I am using Configuration Section Designer (http://csd.codeplex.com/).

#### UPDATE:

here is the error I am getting:

> System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: An error occurred creating the configuration section handler for SendToTestConfig/sendToTestIndexConfig: No parameterless constructor defined for this object. (C:\TFS\Mainline\Business.Utility.SendToTest\Business.Utility.SendToTest\web.config line 20) ---> System.MissingMethodException: No parameterless constructor defined for this object.
>      at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandle& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck)
>      at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean fillCache)
>      at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks, Boolean fillCache)

#### Here is my auto-generated configuration section:

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated by a tool.
//     Runtime Version:4.0.30319.225
//
//     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
//     the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

namespace Business.Utility.SendToTest.Configuration
{


    /// <summary>
    /// The SendToTestIndexConfig Configuration Section.
    /// </summary>
    public partial class SendToTestIndexConfig : global::System.Configuration.ConfigurationSection
    {


        #region Singleton Instance
        /// <summary>
        /// The XML name of the SendToTestIndexConfig Configuration Section.
        /// </summary>
        [global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("ConfigurationSectionDesigner.CsdFileGenerator", "2.0.0.0")]
        internal const string SendToTestIndexConfigSectionName = "sendToTestIndexConfig";

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the SendToTestIndexConfig instance.
        /// </summary>
        [global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("ConfigurationSectionDesigner.CsdFileGenerator", "2.0.0.0")]
        public static global::Business.Utility.SendToTest.Configuration.SendToTestIndexConfig Instance
        {
            get
            {
                return ((global::Business.Utility.SendToTest.Configuration.SendToTestIndexConfig)(global::System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection(global::Business.Utility.SendToTest.Configuration.SendToTestIndexConfig.SendToTestIndexConfigSectionName)));
            }
        }
        #endregion

        #region Xmlns Property
        /// <summary>
        /// The XML name of the <see cref="Xmlns"/> property.
        /// </summary>
        [global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("ConfigurationSectionDesigner.CsdFileGenerator", "2.0.0.0")]
        internal const string XmlnsPropertyName = "xmlns";

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the XML namespace of this Configuration Section.
        /// </summary>
        /// <remarks>
        /// This property makes sure that if the configuration file contains the XML namespace,
        /// the parser doesn't throw an exception because it encounters the unknown "xmlns" attribute.
        /// </remarks>
        [global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("ConfigurationSectionDesigner.CsdFileGenerator", "2.0.0.0")]
        [global::System.Configuration.ConfigurationPropertyAttribute(global::Business.Utility.SendToTest.Configuration.SendToTestIndexConfig.XmlnsPropertyName, IsRequired=false, IsKey=false, IsDefaultCollection=false)]
        public string Xmlns
        {
            get
            {
                return ((string)(base[global::Business.Utility.SendToTest.Configuration.SendToTestIndexConfig.XmlnsPropertyName]));
            }
        }
        #endregion

        #region IsReadOnly override
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets a value indicating whether the element is read-only.
        /// </summary>
        [global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("ConfigurationSectionDesigner.CsdFileGenerator", "2.0.0.0")]
        public override bool IsReadOnly()
        {
            return false;
        }
        #endregion

        #region appGroups Property
        /// <summary>
        /// The XML name of the <see cref="appGroups"/> property.
        /// </summary>
        [global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("ConfigurationSectionDesigner.CsdFileGenerator", "2.0.0.0")]
        internal const string appGroupsPropertyName = "appGroups";

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the appGroups.
        /// </summary>
        [global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("ConfigurationSectionDesigner.CsdFileGenerator", "2.0.0.0")]
        [global::System.ComponentModel.DescriptionAttribute("The appGroups.")]
        [global::System.Configuration.ConfigurationPropertyAttribute(global::Business.Utility.SendToTest.Configuration.SendToTestIndexConfig.appGroupsPropertyName, IsRequired=true, IsKey=false, IsDefaultCollection=false)]
        public global::Business.Utility.SendToTest.Configuration.AppGroupSettingsCollection appGroups
        {
            get
            {
                return ((global::Business.Utility.SendToTest.Configuration.AppGroupSettingsCollection)(base[global::Business.Utility.SendToTest.Configuration.SendToTestIndexConfig.appGroupsPropertyName]));
            }
            set
            {
                base[global::Business.Utility.SendToTest.Configuration.SendToTestIndexConfig.appGroupsPropertyName] = value;
            }
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
namespace Business.Utility.SendToTest.Configuration
{
   ...
```

#### And here is my config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="SendToTestConfig" type="System.Configuration.ConfigurationSectionGroup, System.Configuration, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a">
      <section name="sendToTestIndexConfig" type="Business.Utility.SendToTest.Configuration.SendToTestIndexConfig, Business.Utility.SendToTest.Configuration"/>
    </sectionGroup>
etc.

  </configSections>
    <SendToTestConfig xmlns="Business.Utility.SendToTest.Configuration">
      <sendToTestIndexConfig>
        <appGroups>
          <!-- TODO Change indexFileNamePrefix to desired value-->
          <appGroupSettings name="ItemBased" indexFileNamePrefix="S" indexFolderLocation="C:\TFS\Mainline\Business.Utility.SendToTest\Business.Utility.SendToTest" imageFolderLocation="C:\TFS\Mainline\Business.Utility.SendToTest\Business.Utility.SendToTest">
            <topicEntries>
              <topicEntry topicIDSuffix="DATE" addDuplicateVSAMEntry="true">
                <itemSubFields>
                  <subField index="0" typeName="Date"/>
                </itemSubFields>
              </topicEntry>
              <topicEntry topicIDSuffix="Item" addDuplicateVSAMEntry="true">
                <itemSubFields>
                  <subField index="0" typeName="ItemNumber"/>
                </itemSubFields>
              </topicEntry>
              <topicEntry topicIDSuffix="DESCR">
                <itemSubFields>
                  <subField index="0" typeName="LongDescription"/>
                </itemSubFields>
              </topicEntry>
            </topicEntries>
          </appGroupSettings>
      </appGroups>
    </sendToTestIndexConfig>
  </SendToTestConfig>
...
</configuration>
```

I have tried all of the following, but I keep getting `null` for the first few `config` (which I think makes sense), and getting the abovementioned exception for the rest.

```
//These return null:
SendToTestIndexConfig config = SendToTestIndexConfig.Instance;
//SendToTestIndexConfig config = (SendToTestIndexConfig) ConfigurationManager.GetSection("sendToTestIndexConfig");
//SendToTestIndexConfig configb = (SendToTestIndexConfig)WebConfigurationManager.GetSection("sendToTestIndexConfig");
//SendToTestIndexConfig configc = (SendToTestIndexConfig)WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration(null).GetSection("sendToTestIndexConfig");
//SendToTestIndexConfig configd = (SendToTestIndexConfig)WebConfigurationManager.GetWebApplicationSection("sendToTestIndexConfig");
//SendToTestIndexConfig configf = (SendToTestIndexConfig)WebConfigurationManager.GetSection("sendToTestIndexConfig");


////These throw a "parameterless constructor error" on object "SendToTestConfig/sendToTestIndexConfig"
//SendToTestIndexConfig configg = (SendToTestIndexConfig)WebConfigurationManager.GetSection("SendToTestConfig/sendToTestIndexConfig");
//SendToTestIndexConfig configh = (SendToTestIndexConfig)WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration(null).GetSection("SendToTestConfig/sendToTestIndexConfig");
//SendToTestIndexConfig configi = (SendToTestIndexConfig)WebConfigurationManager.GetWebApplicationSection("SendToTestConfig/sendToTestIndexConfig");
//SendToTestIndexConfig configj = (SendToTestIndexConfig)WebConfigurationManager.GetSection("SendToTestConfig/sendToTestIndexConfig");
```

I'm guessing it has something to do with my naming.  ConfigurationManager.AppSettings works fine, so I know I have the right web.config.

Answer (score 4):

Actually, the solution to the problem is succinctly stated in an example for the `GenericEnumConverter` on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.genericenumconverter%28v=VS.85%29.aspx). I did the same thing you probably did and explicitly set the `[TypeConverter(typeof(GenericEnumConverter))]` attrbibute on one of my configuration section properties and got the same error. According to the documentation for `GenericEnumConverter` linked to above, you do not need to set this attribute in order to use the `GenericEnumConverter` type converter--it is called implicitly by the framework. Remove that attribute from your configuration property specifications, and this error should disappear and everything should just work.

Here is an example of a configuration section property that uses an `Enum`:

```
    public enum UsernameFormat
    {
        DownLevelDomainName,
        UsernameOnly,
        UserPrincipalName
    }

    public class WindowsADElement : ConfigurationElement
    {
        // This property will implicitly use the GenericEnumConverter type converter.
        [ConfigurationProperty("usernameFormat", IsRequired=true, DefaultValue=UsernameFormat.UserPrincipalName)]
        public UsernameFormat UsernameFormat
        {
            get { return (UsernameFormat)this["usernameFormat"]; }
            set { this["usernameFormat"] = value; }
    }
```

Then, to use it in code:

```
    MyConfigurationSection config = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("myConfigurationSection") as MyConfigurationSection;
    UsernameFormat format = config.UsernameLookup.WindowsAD.UsernameFormat;
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: It sure did help. Once I removed the GenericEnumConverter it started working.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if this is the best solution, but I was able to get around the problem.  The error was because I was using the `GenericEnumTypeConverter` class to convert the config strings to the `AppGroup` and `SubFieldTypes` enums.  I created my own custom TypeConverters, and it solved the problem.  Apparently, `GenericEnumTypeConverter` has no parameterless constructors, requiring the enum type for the constructor.  Would love to know if there is a way to use `GenericEnumTypeConverter`, but this worked for me.

This clued me in on the answer: [Configuration Error With Custom Behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3659844/configuration-error-with-custom-behaviour)